# Rails: How to prevent routing clashes with static and dynamic pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, name-collision

I have the following route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/:id', to: 'foo#bar', constraints: { id:  /\d+/ }
end
```

*/1* loads my record with id #1. The problem is that my route conflicts with Rails default static pages (404, 500, etc ...).

How can I have static error pages with my dynamic routes working?

If it's possible, I don't mind moving my static pages to a route like */errors/404*, for example.

**EDIT 1**:

Reopening ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions class and changing the private method render_exception is a extremely hacky solution:

config/application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes
  end
end

module ActionDispatch
  class ShowExceptions
    private
      def render_exception(request, exception)
        backtrace_cleaner = request.get_header "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"
        wrapper = ExceptionWrapper.new(backtrace_cleaner, exception)
        status  = wrapper.status_code
        request.set_header "action_dispatch.exception", wrapper.exception
        request.set_header "action_dispatch.original_path", request.path_info
        request.path_info = "/errors/#{status}"
        response = @exceptions_app.call(request.env)
        response[1]["X-Cascade"] == "pass" ? pass_response(status) : response
      rescue Exception => failsafe_error
        $stderr.puts "Error during failsafe response: #{failsafe_error}\n  #{failsafe_error.backtrace * "\n  "}"
        FAILSAFE_RESPONSE
      end
  end
end
```

I've changed `request.path_info = "/#{status}"` to `request.path_info = "/errors/#{status}"`.

I don't like this solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the directory that renders exceptions. You will need to change some configuration, so for example you could put the following in `config/application.rb` within your `Application` class:

```
config.exceptions_app = ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path.join('errors'))
```

Then move those static `404.html` and `500.html` from `public` to a newly created `public/errors` dir.

Comment: Will it generate a new route for my static errors? "/errors/500" instead of "/500" ?

Comment: It should. The problem is anything in the `public` dir will hide any app routes, so we needed to move those numbered `.html` files somewhere else. But you then have to let Rails know what to render in case of exceptions, which is why that config is necessary.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.
Please, see my edit with an awful hacky solution :P

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is anything in the public dir will hide any app routes, so we needed to move those numbered .html files somewhere else."? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I see. I have fixed with your solution without any side effects. At least I did not saw anything wrong until now ... Thanks!